# AWS : EFS CLI Query based on Name

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-efs

So have a req to filterout EFS based on Tags (Name or App code)

for EFS we cant use filter so the only way is to query so im getting the whole list by the below query but is there anyway can i query based on EFS Name like myTest* in my case, provides only EFS that matches name myTest*

```
aws efs describe-file-systems --query "FileSystems[*].{FileSystemID:FileSystemId, Name:Name, SizeinBytes: SizeInBytes.Value}| []|reverse(sort_by(@, &SizeinBytes))" --region="us-east-1" --output table
```

Tried this but no luck:

```
aws efs describe-file-systems --query FileSystems[?Name=='myTest*'].FileSystemId --region us-east-1 --output text
```

Please assist

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Do you want to find efs based on efs name(which you should know ) or only tags?

Comment: hi @Riz yes find efs  based on Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aws efs describe-file-systems  --query 'FileSystems[?Name==`$name`].FileSystemId' --region $region.
```

You are missing "`" with your second trial.

If you want to get the name of all the files systems you can first use the following query to find the name of the `EFS` and then the previous query to get the `FileSystemId`.

```
aws efs describe-file-systems  --query 'FileSystems[*].Name' --region $region
```

Or you can get both `FileSystemId` and the name of the `EFS` with the following query.

```
aws efs describe-file-systems  --query 'FileSystems[].[Name, FileSystemId]' --region $region
```

Comment: Thankyou @Riz is there anyway can i sue a Flag (*) like wild card myTest* to get all filesystem with Name matches myTest* ?

Comment: Check the updated answer.